# Transform.LookAt Bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

My game is giving me a bug when I'm using transform.LookAt();

Here is a screen shot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/n010G.jpg

I have a car that is on the ground, but the bug makes it stand on its end.

Code:

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position,transform.position)< MaxDistnace)
    {
        transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the bug is? The picture you have linked doesn't really explain much.

Comment: The bug makes the car moe  from ground to stand like that

Comment: Post your code in your question, and then we may be able to help :)

Comment: Posted! just some of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to do with the way your car is created. LookAt() will just make the object face the target, regardless of what axis it is on.

***A quick way to fix it*** (not necessarily the best) is to create an empty GameObject and make the car a child of the empty GameObject.

Then rotate the car 90 degrees in whichever direction is wrong. If the car rotates 90 degress forwards the wrong way, then rotate it 90 degress backwards.

Remove the script from the car and add it to the empty GameObject.

Looking at your code again, perhaps a few things to try before the above:

`transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform)` should probably be `Player.transform` unless you have created a variable to hold this called `PlayerTransform`.

Rename your `MaxDistnace` to `maxDistance` this is much better coding practice.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT** Alternatively, your player could be directly above your car, which is why the car is facing up! Put your player on the same level as your car and see if that makes a difference too!